# WPF image's gotfocus/lostfocus event does not fired

Tags: c#, wpf, events

Could You please help me, why GotFocus and LostFocusa event doesn't fired when I Click to image and then to textbox?

My XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="imageclick.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="Untitled.png" GotFocus="GF" LostFocus="LF" Focusable="True"></Image>
            <TextBox ></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I could not understand why GotFocus/LostFocus event never fired

Thanks in advance

Update: When I set the tabindex, when the tab reached the image event fired, but I could not reach with mouse click

Comment: I'm guessing that Image's can't be focused at all. You might need to wrap the Image tag in a "focusable" element.

Comment: I found the followings: The Image class is not a true control class in that it is not a descendant class of Control. You can't call focus to an Image element, or place an Image element in a tab sequence. Which element can I use to wrap the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image isn't a **[`Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.aspx)**. Only **Controls** can get **focus**.Instead of GotFocus and LostFocus use **MouseEnter** and **MouseLeave** events,

```
 <StackPanel>
            <Image Stretch="Uniform" Source="Untitled.png"   Height="410" MouseEnter="Image_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Image_MouseLeave"></Image>
            <TextBox Height="65"></TextBox>
 </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks, But I would like to reach somehow that the image is selected ot not. For example a border outside an image if it is selected

Answer (score -1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.gotfocus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), UIElement.GotFocus event occurs when this element gets logical focus.

And logical focus differs from keyboard focus, it is raised when the value of the `IsFocused` property of an element in the route is changed from false to true.

So, in order to achieve it through mouse clicks, need to handle the respective mouse button events or simply handle `MouseDown` and set the focus to the sender.

```
private void Image_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is Image)
        {
            (sender as Image).Focus();
        }
    }
```

This will set the `IsFocused` property of the Image to `true`.

Comment: this is a bad idea, because there are multiple ways to change focus. If you pressed tab to switch to a different control, etc, you'd have to capture all those scenarios in order to implement gotfocus / lostfocus properly.

Comment: As the `Image` behaviour is little strange here, this is the ugly hack, to achieve the desirable output. Along with handling `GotFocus` and `LostFocus`, if we handle `MouseDown`; its working fine. I believe, there are lots of other ways to achieve the same, but this also working.